# Error building on VSO / Azure - Typescript compiler not found

Tags: azure, typescript, azure-devops

Since yesterday i keep getting this error when trying to build on hosted VSO (Azure )with a standard buildcontroller:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets (87, 0)
Your project file uses a different version of the TypeScript compiler and tools than is currently installed on this machine. No compiler was found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.5\tsc.exe. You may be able to fix this problem by changing the  element in your project file.

We are using Visual Studio 2013 and Typescript 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue and have help you submitted a feedback on Microsoft Connect Page, refer to this link for details: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2292339

For now, you can use vNext build system to build your project as workaround, the build can be completed successfully.

Or copy the required files for Microsoft.TypeScript.targets to source control folder and change the path references in the csproj file to this folder as mentioned in this article: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1518. In my case, the build works on Hosted Build Controller after I upload "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript" folder to source control and update the csproj file to refer to this folder.